# Is it possible for a winform to have an animation effect if it is in a parent container?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I have a winform application using C#. I have tried everything to have a transition effect from form1 to form2.(opacity and height width change base on timer) But it seems that using parent-child container (MdiParent), it is not possible. Am I right? Or there are other way?

Here is my code..

```
public static System.Windows.Forms.Form gMdiForm;

public static Boolean fCheckFormNotUsed(string tMdiChildFormName)
    {
        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Form childform in gMdiForm.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (childform.Name == tMdiChildFormName)
            {
                childform.Visible = true;
                childform.Activate();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

if (fCheckFormNotUsed("frm2"))
        {
            frm2 mMDIChild = new frm2();
            mMDIChild.MdiParent = cls0G.gMdiForm;
            mMDIChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            mMDIChild.Opacity = 0;
            mMDIChild.Show();

        }
```

Here is the code for timer in frm2

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Opacity <= 1.0)
        {
            this.Opacity += 0.07;
            this.Height += 1;
            this.Width  += 3;

        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Here is the load for form2

```
        this.Opacity = 0;
        timer1.Start();
```

Comment: it is possible with the correct code. But, without knowing your code and what you want to do exactly with the form and which kind of animation you want to show? it is not possible to give any suggestion. You have said that `I have tried everything`. but, you haven't shown your code what you have tried. If somewhere mistake in your code then we can suggest you and try to resolve issue. but, for that you have to show your code at-least.

Comment: @Nimesh sorry.. I added my code above..

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/196249/Cant-able-to-make-mdi-child-as-transparent

Comment: You can stop trying, it is not possible.  Opacity and TransparencyKey are only possible for top-level windows.  Works on the MdiParent, can't work on any MDI child window.  Windows 8 is the first Windows version that can make these properties work on any window, but getting that supported by .NET is future music right now.